# Print getters when and object is printed in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Is there an option in TypeScript/JavaScript to print an object who has private properties using their getters instead of printing the private properties names.

By example I have this class in TypeScript

```js
class Vehicle {

  constructor(private _brand: string, private _year: number) {}

  get brand(): string {
    return this._brand;
  }

  get year(): number {
    return this._year;
  }

  set year(year: number) {
    this._year = year;
  }

  set brand(brand: string) {
    this._brand = brand;
  }
}

const vehicle: Vehicle = new Vehicle('Toyota', 10);

console.log(vehicle);
```

I got this

```
[LOG]: Vehicle: {
  "_brand": "Toyota",
  "_year": 10
}
```

But I'm wondering if I can get something like this

```
[LOG]: Vehicle: {
  "brand": "Toyota",
  "year": 10
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between `private` in TypeScript and [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) in JavaScript. `console.log(vehicle);` is evaluated in JavaScript and there the properties are public.

Comment: Private class properties in TypeScript are public in JavaScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeBYAUL60wA9gHYQAuATgK7DlGUAUADpcgG5jnoD6ARpTAkAJgC5oFNiQDmAGmisOXXgE94YSuJLUAtn3iUAlJgC+ufNGnxy0AUOGND4ychmYLBSteqUS0cigQAHT8giIA3BZmeDgEVjZqGo5auvqU7rEE0F7kPn4ByME8iZSRmdEWENbQJYwlKXoGxtiZBAVFJdAAvDXqpVHmmVU2diKMo2ISVK7SzR7+gSET3bZhwmUE0RU4xGQ27EioIPDiCChoKyTwAO5wh2iMAOQAKkQqRORgj-IAjAAMhjKuF2ECIxyCICI0kYB3Ox0BQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `console.log` does varies by environment. If you want to do what you're describing, you'd have to write your own logger function instead, for instance (in JavaScript, but types are fairly easily added) see comments:

```
function log(obj) {
    // Get the names of getter properties defined on the prototype
    const ctor = obj.constructor;
    const proto = ctor?.prototype;
    const names = new Set(
        proto
            ? Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(proto))
                .filter(([_, {get}]) => !!get)
                .map(([name]) => name)
            : []
    );
    // Add in the names of "own" properties that don't start with "_"
    for (const name of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (!name.startsWith("_")) {
            names.add(name);
        }
    }
    // Create a simple object with the values of those properties
    const simple = {};
    for (const name of names) {
        simple[name] = obj[name];
    }
    // See if we can get a "constructor" name for it, apply it if so
    let objName =
        obj[Symbol.toStringTag]
        || ctor?.name;
    if (objName) {
        simple[Symbol.toStringTag] = objName;
    }
    // Log it
    console.log(simple);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";

function log(obj) {
    // Get the names of getter properties defined on the prototype
    const ctor = obj.constructor;
    const proto = ctor?.prototype;
    const names = new Set(
        proto
            ? Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(proto))
                .filter(([_, {get}]) => !!get)
                .map(([name]) => name)
            : []
    );
    // Add in the names of "own" properties that don't start with "_"
    for (const name of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (!name.startsWith("_")) {
            names.add(name);
        }
    }
    // Create a simple object with the values of those properties
    const simple = {};
    for (const name of names) {
        simple[name] = obj[name];
    }
    // See if we can get a "constructor" name for it, apply it if so
    let objName =
        obj[Symbol.toStringTag]
        || ctor?.name;
    if (objName) {
        simple[Symbol.toStringTag] = objName;
    }
    // Log it
    console.log(simple);
}

class Vehicle {
    constructor(_brand, _year) {
        this._brand = _brand;
        this._year = _year;
    }
    get brand() {
        return this._brand;
    }
    get year() {
        return this._year;
    }
    set year(year) {
        this._year = year;
    }
    set brand(brand) {
        this._brand = brand;
    }
}
const vehicle = new Vehicle('Toyota', 10);
log(vehicle);
```

Lots of room to tweak that how you like it, that's just a sketch of how you might go about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering if there was a native way to do it. If we are working with OOP private properties names should not be exposed even from the console log right?.

Comment: @VíctorCardozo - That would depend entirely on the implementation of the console logging function, but usually I'd expect them to be shown since `console.log` is a debugging tool. It's also useful to remember that TypeScript "private" properties are only private from a compile-time perspective; at runtime, they're normal public properties. But even truly private fields (JavaScript has those now) are shown by Chrome's devtools console (but not Node.js's).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that, but you could create a log method in the class, like this:

```
  log() {
    console.log({
      brand: this.brand,
      year: this.year,
    });
  }
```

And then simply call `vehicle.log();`

You'd then get a log like this `{brand: 'Toyota', year: 10}`